# playready license server request only get

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv, playready

I use the following implementation for PlayReady on Samsung Smart TV SDK 3.5 & 4.x.

Now, in my network traces I see a plain GET Request to the license server URL being executed, but no data passed.
What could be the cause for this?

This is my code:

```
var VideoURL = '.........bution_deu_20_9000K.ism/Manifest';
var serverLicense = '...LicenseAcquisition.asmx';
var customData = '.....';

player.InitPlayer(VideoURL+"|COMPONENT=WMDRM");// + "|COMPONENT=WMDRM"
player.SetPlayerProperty(4, serverLicense, serverLicense.length);
player.SetPlayerProperty(3, customData, customData.length);
player.StartPlayback();
```

Thanks

Comment: I cannot help you with your problem but I can confirm that this sequence of operations works for me. Well, I do the SetPlayerProperty calls in the opposite order but that probably does not affect anything. Perhaps there is a problem with the video, leading to unexpected behavior? If you can post a minimal demo app with a working video, perhaps I can spot the critical factor.

Comment: Hi Sander! It is a video and server that is not available to public. After a lot of tests, I assume that it is an issue with the PR-Server - although I have no idea why. Can you see the request/response with the PR Server in wireshark or any other tool?

Comment: Yes, the PlayReady license request and response can be viewed via Wireshark. If the server uses HTTPS, you will need to decrypt the SSL connection using the private key of the licensing server (see http://blogs.technet.com/b/nettracer/archive/2013/10/12/decrypting-ssl-tls-sessions-with-wireshark-reloaded.aspx?Redirected=true)